# What function fires when UICollectionView paging is done?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView with 3 items on screen and when the animation finishes to go to the next one, I want to call some code, what method should I use? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. To detect when a paginated scroll has finished you can use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_:)`

See the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619417-scrollviewdidenddecelerating)